# plugin/extension for chrome or Firefox to control internet speed for html page testing

Tags: html, testing, frontend

I'm looking for a plugin/extension for chrome or Firefox that allows controlling the internet connection speed, to simulate how the page going to load for slow internet connections.

please let me know if you know any.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler) is really helpful for this task.

Comment: i just found out that there is fiddler for Mac http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono I'll check it out, hopefully it dose the job.